# Docking a fixed nav bar to the top on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a nav bar that is positioned in the middle of a page to "dock" with the top of the browser when it is scrolled to, and undock when the browser is scrolled back up past it. Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/gLQtx/

```
  $(function() {
     var initPos = $('#stickyNav').offset().top;
     console.log(initPos);
    $(window).bind('scroll',function() {
        var vPos = $(window).scrollTop(); 
         if( vPos > initPos ) {
          $('#stickyNav').css('position', 'fixed'); 
          $('#stickyNav').css('top', '0');
        } else {
          $('#stickyNav').css('position', 'absolute'); 
          $('#stickyNav').css('top', '0'); 


        }
    });
    });
```

Comment: your jsfiddle and your posted code don't match up. which one are you trying to use?

Comment: One thing that is important to realize is that in order to accomplish your requirements the scroll event will be triggered many times unnecessarily and that will decrease the page performance.
However if you really want to do it you're in the right way. On scroll event you need to check if the distance to the top of the DISPLAYED page (not all page) is <=0

Comment: Just checked your jsfiddle and it is right, you found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I overlooked you asked about undocking as well.

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLQtx/8/). *(Update: There's an [even newer one here](http://jsfiddle.net/gLQtx/9/).)*

It includes a change to the HTML and CSS. Basically I added a container around the stickynav so the jquery can calculate based on the container, and then target the stickynav for fixed position. That way the container still has an offset while the stickynav is position fixed.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="stickyNav_container">
            <div id="stickyNav">
                <ul>
                    <li>Menu Item</li>
                    <li>Menu Item</li>
                    <li>Menu Item</li>
                    <li>Menu Item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin:auto;
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    position:relative;
    background:black;
}
#stickyNav_container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 300px;
}
#stickyNav_container, #stickyNav {
    background:white;
    height: 60px;
    width: 300px;
}
#stickyNav ul {
    float:left;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        var vPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var totalH = $('#stickyNav_container').offset().top;
        var finalSize = totalH - vPos;

        console.log(finalSize);

        if (finalSize <= 0) {
            $('#stickyNav').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                    'top': 0
            })
        } else {
            $('#stickyNav').css({
                'position': 'static'
            })
        }
    });
});
```

---

OLD ANSWER:

Check out this updated jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/gLQtx/4/

However, note that after it hits the nav once, the position is fixed to the top and the offset of that element will then always be 0 or less. so the nav will never "return" to it's original position with the script you've got here.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        var vPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var totalH = $('#stickyNav').offset().top;
        var finalSize = totalH - vPos;

        console.log(finalSize);

        if (finalSize <= 0) {
            $('#stickyNav').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                    'top': 0
            })
        } else {
            $('#stickyNav').css({
                'position': 'absolute'
            })
        }
    });
});
```